# Format JodaTime LocalDate in SpringMvc JSON using formatter

Tags: json, spring, format, jodatime

I have a problem with my Spring application.
How can I format a `LocalDate` in a JSON...
The problem is that when I send the JSON I have to send a number, but when Spring generate the JSON I have:

```
"data": {
    "weekyear": 1970,
    "weekOfWeekyear": 1,
    "chronology": {
        "zone": {
            "fixed": true,
            "id": "UTC"
        }
    },
    "monthOfYear": 1,
    "yearOfEra": 1970,
    ...and a lot more
```

I have my field with the annotation `DateTimeFormat` like:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate data;
```

And also configurated the format service in my `servlet-context.xml`:

```
<beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
 </beans:bean>
```

But this alone doesn't work, what I miss to configure?